# Can you please identify the and correct the Syntax for the following line?

Tags: syntax

1. int [5] myArray = new integer [];

Comment: You may want to read what is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Syntax errors should generally be solved on your own after reading some documentation on arrays, for example.

Comment: It's hard to believe that someone could be *so* lazy that they couldn't even be bothered to remove the question number that clearly marks this as some sort of classwork. I wish you well in your career and am thankful that I'll be retired before you can cause any real damage. Please, for the love of whatever gods you believe in, steer clear of train control systems or nuclear power plant management software :-)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the syntax. Good luck!

```
int[] array = new int[5];
```

Comment: seems you missed the "identify" part

Comment: @amuse Oops yeah missed that. The error is that the [5] should be on the right side of the equal sign, and both sides of the equal sign should have int, not one side having integer.